# Выполнение блоков END { ... }

Tags: perl

Как вы знаете, блоки `END { ... }` выполняются снизу вверх. Т.е. если в скрипте имеется 4 блока `END { ... }`, то сначала отработает самый последний блок в нашем скрипте, а самый первый блок - последним.

**Ситуация:** Если у меня есть 4 блока, и мне необходимо, чтобы сначала отработал четвертый блок, потом начал третий, и, если в третьем блоке выполнится условие, то продолжить выполнять второй блок, и первый, а если условие не выполнится - то соотвественно, второй и первый блоки не должны отработать.

**Вопрос:** Вот как реализовать это именно с блоками `END { ... }`? Или здесь никакой проблемы нет, и просто надо почитать что-нибудь?

Дико не минусуйте меня, я не особо шарю в перле, и это вопрос скорее, чтобы понять что там и как работает. Если написал бред, напишите в комменты - удалю. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отрабатывать блоки будут в любом случае и именно в обратном порядке, на это вы повлиять не можете.

Но можете в блок добавить условие:

```
my $end_control;
END{
  if( $end_control eq 'continue' ) { 
     тут код, который не выполнится, если $end_control не 'continue'
  }
}

END{
  if( 2>3 ){ $end_control = 'continue'; }
}
```

Почитать можете [тут](https://perlmaven.com/end) и [тут](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html#BEGIN%2c-UNITCHECK%2c-CHECK%2c-INIT-and-END)